# wxPython threaded UDP server

Tags: python, sockets, multithreading, wxpython, udp

I am trying to put together a UDP server with a wxPython GUI.

Here is a link to the code:

[UDP Server pastie.org](http://www.pastie.org/private/gwxiukbngv13p30tzkyzjq)

I have linked it as its pretty lengthy.  I have successfully got the UDP server running on the thread but I can not figure out how to close the socket when the stopping the thread.

At the moment it will kick up a new thread each time you click start but I will be removing this.  Is it possible to close the socket from running when the thread is stopped?

If I am doing this the complete wrong way any advice is appreciated.

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python Twisted. It has wxPython integration with twisted.internet.wxreactor and makes networking easy and threadless.

```
from twisted.internet import wxreactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol

wxreactor.install()

class MyProtocol(DatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):
        print "received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)
        self.transport.write(data, (host, port))

# <GUI code>
# to start listening do port = reactor.listenUDP(<port>, MyProtocol())
# to stop do self.transport.stopListening() in MyProtocol
# or port.stopListening() from outside

from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.registerWxApp(app)
reactor.run()
```